# Passing URI variables in CodeIgniter and MongoDB

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have a function in my controller in CodeIgniter which is as follows:

```
public function age($var = null) 
{
    $data = $this->mongo_db
        ->where('age', $var)
        ->get('users');

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

When I navigate to http://www.siteurl.com/controller/age/25 it should bring back all the documents with an age of 25, however it's not returning any data.

If I amend the query to the below it works fine...

```
public function age($var = null) 
{
    $data = $this->mongo_db
        ->where('age', 25)
        ->get('users');

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

It's probably something very simple, but I'm new to codeigniter and I just can't see what's going wrong!

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong. From the code you posted, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it. Can you post the output of `var_dump(func_get_args());`?

Comment: The output is `array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "20" }`. If I do a simple echo $var, it will print the variable... it just seems to be the mongo_db query thats ignoring the variable.

Comment: In that case, you might want to mention which library are you using. To my knowledge, there are more than one MongoDB library for CI. And you probably would be better off consulting with the library author.

Comment: Good point! I should've mentioned that straight away. I'm using the [Alex Bilbie Codeigniter mongo library](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library)

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump($this->mongo_db->where);`? Right after you call the `where()` method of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference I can see between the two is that `$var` is a string rather than an integer. I can't test this right now, but I suspect you need to typecast the variable to an integer before passing it of to Alex's library.

```
$data = $this->mongo_db
    ->where('age', (int) $var)
    ->get('users');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function age($var = false) 
{
    if ($var) {
       $data = $this->mongo_db
           ->where('age', $var)
           ->get('users');

       echo "<pre>";
       print_r($data);
       echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately this doesn't seem to fork either. It seems like MongoDb query isn't allowing the variable to be passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

did you config any route? put something like this in the config

```
$route['controller/age/(:num)'] = "controller/age/$1";
```

Comment: The routing is working fine. I can print the variable with a simple 'echo $var', it's just the mongo_db query that isn't using the variable.